# Xmgrace: linear regression using error bars

Tags: xmgrace

The question is really simple: how do I perform a linear regression using errorbars on Xmgrace? 
I know I have to load the data as XYDY (my file is a 3-column file with y-errors on the third column), but I just can't figure out how to tell him to use the error bars when performing linear regeression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your ASCII data as a **Single Set** and set the Set Type to **XYDY**.

I created the following example data in the file "data.dat":

```
#X Y Yerr
0 0.2 0.2
1 0.55 0.2
2 0.58 0.2
3 0.81 0.2
4 0.9 0.4
5 1.3 0.4
<Bonus tip: Grace seems to like each row to have a line break at the end!>
```

In the Data menu choose Transformations > regression.
Apply to the correct set; in this case it is the only data set so I use set `S0`.
The type of fit should be **Linear**. Use **Fitted Values** and whichever Restrictions you see as fit.

Click OK and you should see your new fit line. 
The Grace Console will report what happened:

[image: Grace Console output from linear regression.]

A new data set `S1` should now be available, containing the regression results.

Here is my resulting plot:
[image]

Enjoy!